# How is Twitter Bootstrap's doc website made?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I mean this website: http://getbootstrap.com/

I looked into the code at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/docs

I think the `.html` is not typical HTML? For example

For [CSS page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), the [source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/css.html) is:

```
---
layout: default
title: CSS
slug: css
lead: "Global CSS settings, fundamental HTML elements styled and enhanced with extensible classes, and an advanced grid system."
---


{% include css/overview.html %}
{% include css/grid.html %}
{% include css/type.html %}
{% include css/code.html %}
{% include css/tables.html %}
{% include css/forms.html %}
{% include css/buttons.html %}
{% include css/images.html %}
{% include css/helpers.html %}
{% include css/responsive-utilities.html %}
{% include css/less.html %}
{% include css/sass.html %}
```

Specifically, what's the programming language, framework for building the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skimming the [build program](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) shows that it uses [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/), which is written in Ruby.